# Winforms, how to update pages in pdf using a thread

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, axacropdf

I have a `Main.cs` and a `Pdf.cs`. My Main.cs has 3 buttons, everytime you click on each button it navigates to the page of a pdf file in Pdf.cs. Ex. you click button 1, a new window will popup and displays the pdf file at page 1. If you click button 2, it will display a new pdf popup window page 2 and so on.

My question is, is there a way that the pdf file will only open 1 pdf file and everytime the user click the button it will just **update/invoke** the selected page?

Here's the sample code, Main.cs:

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadStartSOP = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => ThreadScreen(pageNumber)));
    if(ThreadStartSOP.IsAlive)
    {
        //Update the page
    }
    else
    {
        ThreadStartSOP.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        ThreadStartSOP.Start();
    }
}

private void ThreadScreen(int pageNumber)
{
    Application.Run(new pdf(pageNumber));
}
```

Pdf.cs

```
public pdf(int page)
{
    this.axAcroPDF1.src = @"c:\example.pdf";
    this.axAcroPDF1.setCurrentPage(page);
}

public void UpdatePDFPage(int page)
{
    this.axAcroPDF1.setCurrentPage(page); //Not updating..
    //I tried creating delegate, then invoking the method to it 
    //and still no luck in updating the pdf pages..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I cant tell if Pdf.cs is a form - or something else; but basically there is no reference to the form you launched; with a reference to the winform, you can then invoke the methods on that form from the main form.

Something like this should do the trick

```
    Pdf pdfReference;

    private void dummyPage2()
    {
        if (pdfReference != null)
        pdfReference.UpdatePDFPage(2);
    }


    private void ThreadScreen(int pageNumber)
    {
        pdfReference = new Pdf(1);
        Application.Run(pdfReference);
    }
```

Comment: Pdf.cs is a winform. Your code is same as my code. Thanks for answering tho.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "your code is same" - note the referential object is **pdfReference = new Pdf(1)**; inside the ThreadScreen. and not the thread that you have in your code.

Comment: Hi @zxed, `Application.Run(pdfReference);` is starting a new thread/window. What I want is a single thread/window. Thanks for your answer